# JPA multitenancy implementation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, amazon-redshift

I'm faced with a new challenge of supporting multi-tenancy with JPA. I've searched around and it looks like JPA doesn't really offer anything that is usable in the long run. I see a lot of people talking about spring security and picking the tenant datasource from it's context. I don't want to use hibernate or eclipseLink too. Not sure what is the best solution for my problem.

I have an independent service running that needs to kick off queries to various database at random times. I am currently using AWS Redshift as my data store. I will have a connection string available to me as requests come in. I am really un-easy as to what platforms to use to accomplish this? My service is also using spring boot.   Anyone have any thoughts? Thank you!!

Comment: what are your problems with eclipselink? Toplink also supports multitenancy : https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/multitenancy.htm#TLADG489

Comment: I just don't know eclipseLink or Toplink. Inquiring for fast one off solutions. I'm just trying to move fast. Not sure if eclipseLink will allow that?

Comment: of course it will - but searching for "fast" solutions is _always_ the cause of many, many mistakes. Either take your time, research, test, implement and test again or ... drop the project because you might get into legal problems if you knowingly ignore security risks, **especially** most ORM architectures require a whole lot of experience and/or research if one wants to use it in business applications
http://codecrafters.blogspot.de/2013/03/multi-tenant-cloud-applications-with.html

Comment: Hibernate [supports multi tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) out-of-the-box... So why wouldn't that be *usable in the long run*. We also [implemented a custom (generic) solution](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) once that is still running after ~10 yrs in production.

Comment: Definitely true. I was going to try to use Spring security to handle access to each datasource. I've used hibernate, but with the current requirements I'm not sure hibernate can handle what is needed.

I first have to take  a plain sql statement and execute it to get the population. Without doing all of this in memory and worrying about running out of space I am creating a temp table on the fly. I haven't found a way to create a pojo representing this temp table so that I can use my other object to form queries and join on it.